# What is the type of asynchronous iterator?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, typing

Example (question follows):

```
import asyncio
import typing as t

from aiokafka import AIOKafkaConsumer


class KafkaSimpleClient:

    ...

    async def receive(self, topic: str) -> ???:
        bootstrap_servers = ','.join(
            '{}:{}'.format(host, port)
            for host, port in self._bootstrap_servers
        )
        consumer = AIOKafkaConsumer(
            loop=asyncio.get_event_loop(),
            bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers,
            metadata_max_age_ms=5000,
        )
        consumer.subscribe(pattern=topic)
        await consumer.start()
        return consumer
```

Now, I'm struggling with the return type of `receive` (it returns something that can be iterated over with `async for x in y`.  What is it?  Is it an awaitable iterator?  Is it an iterator over awaitables?  Perhaps something else entirely?

- `??? = t.Awaitable[t.Iterator]`
- `??? = t.Iterator[t.Awaitable]`
- `??? = (Something else)`

Comment: What does it matter what it is? Python is a dynamic language so it shouldn't matter. You seem to know that you can use `async for x in y:` so that seems to be an end to the matter.

Comment: @quamrana You seem to be able to read the question, but you don't know the answer. What is the point of your comment?

Comment: Well, I still want to know why it matters to you what the type is. If you were to know what the type is, what would you do with the information?

Comment: @quamrana curiosity? documentation? future-proofing against typechecker? This is a legitimate part of the language, which has its uses. It's for programmers to decide whether they want to use it or not, but a factual question about how it actually works doesn't have a personal aspect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f350a268a7071ce7d7a5bb86a9b1229782d4963b/Lib/typing.py#L1730) of `typing` module leaves no doubts.

```
async def receive(self, topic: str) -> t.AsyncIterable:
```

or

```
async def receive(self, topic: str) -> t.AsyncIterator:
```

if you sure it'll be strictly iterator.

Answer (score 0):

As of Python 3.9, `typing.AsyncIterable` and `typing.AsyncIterator` are deprecated aliases to their abstract base class (ABC) counterparts in `collections.abc`. The ABCs can also be subscripted with the type of the iterator's items, which allows the type of those items to be inferred when iterating.

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/typing.html#typing.AsyncIterable) for `typing.AsyncIterable`:

> *Deprecated since version 3.9:* [`collections.abc.AsyncIterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.AsyncIterable) now supports `[]`.

Thus, using the new ABC types and subscripts, the return type of `receive` becomes:

```
import collections.abc as abc
from aiokafka.structs import ConsumerRecord

async def receive(self, topic: str) -> abc.AsyncIterable[ConsumerRecord]:
    ...

# or

async def receive(self, topic: str) -> abc.AsyncIterator[ConsumerRecord]:
    ...
```

(Where `ConsumerRecord` is the type of items supplied by the `AIOKafkaConsumer` iterator, [as documented](https://aiokafka.readthedocs.io/en/stable/consumer.html).)

---

However, the same [docs](https://aiokafka.readthedocs.io/en/stable/consumer.html) for `AIOKafkaConsumer` tell us:

> Failure to call `AIOKafkaConsumer.stop()` after consumer use *will leave background tasks running*.

Thus, in this specific example, the return type of `receive` should probably not abstract the concrete type, since the consumer must be aware that the return value is a resource that must be cleaned up and not just any iterator.